# CSS Grid that Does NOT Expand the Full Width

Tags: css, css-grid

**NOTE:**  I have also made a video explaining my question:  https://www.loom.com/share/9ebf0ab686b54ad9a36bffe375098e49

---

I have set up the following CSS Grid:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr 60px;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header'
    'main sidebar'
    'footer footer';
  min-height: 100vh;
`
```

This basically works as it should -- it gives me a header, footer, main content section and sidebar.

What I would like to do, though, is center the Main and Sidebar sections -- rather than have them span 100% of the width.  As an example, we can take a look at the basic page layout of this site:  https://thrivethemes.com/blog/

I'd like to do something similar using CSS Grid -- that is to say, have the same layout, but just be have the Main and Sidebar sections combined add up to 1180px (on large screens).

Now, here is one solution I thought of:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 880px 300px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr 60px;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header'
    '. main sidebar .'
    'footer footer footer footer';
```

And it works.  But I'm wondering if there is a better way -- one that doesn't require me creating extra columns that I don't need to use?

Comment: Nope, that's the way it should be done. Oh, and you are using the "extra columns" for the header/footer.

Comment: Of course, the alternative is not to have the header/footer *in the grid at all*. Just wrap the main/siderbar in a div and center/max-width **that**.

Comment: Your HTML would be useful. Can this be changed?

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for all of your comments.  I can change the HTML -- and, indeed, I did change it up a bit (while still using CSS Grid).  In the meantime, thanks again for your comments and suggestions.